# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes Randomly with 8 GB RAM and 1TB HARD DISK (crash report)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

Recently, I have installed Ubuntu 18 & then upgrade it to Ubuntu 19.10.
On the other side, I have Windows 10 OS. 
During the partition of the disk, I allow 218 GB for Ubuntu and rest for Windows 10 (as shown in the figure).
However, Ubuntu 19.10 freezes randomly, during it nothing works including keyboard, mouse, ttly, SysRq(I have tried most of the key), nothing. The only option I have is to hard power off through power button.

I have tried everything, I updated all the software, fix the ubuntu through boot, clean files, every thing also check the crash files in /var/crash/ nothing found there.

My laptop has 8GB Ram, 2 GB shared Graphics card (AMD RYZEN 5) with 8 GB RAM, 1TB Hard Disk, Laptop model: Acer 315-41 Model.

**I got the crash report in** /var/crash 
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash 
 _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload

> First few line of _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash :

```
ProblemType:  
Crash Architecture: 
amd64 CurrentDesktop: 
ubuntu:GNOME

Date: Tue Mar 10 00:27:20 2020 DistroRelease: Ubuntu 19.10

ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/gnome-shell ExecutableTimestamp: 1572020538

ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/gnome-shell ProcCwd: /home/muhammad

ProcEnviron:  LANG=en_IN  LANGUAGE=en_IN:en  PATH=(custom, no user) 

SHELL=/bin/bash  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set> ProcMaps: 

194b478b5000-194b478c5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b478c5000-194b478e5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
194b478e5000-194b47915000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b47915000-194b47955000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b47955000-194b47965000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
194b47965000-194b47985000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b47985000-194b47995000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
194b47995000-194b479a5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b479a5000-194b479c5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b479c5000-194b479d5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0  
194b479d5000-194b479e5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
194b479e5000-194b479f5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0
```

Please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BZDT.png)

Comment: There is no such release as Ubuntu 18,  Ubuntu Core 18 is an IoT appliance intended release and not a server/desktop release (which use *yy.mm* format), however Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is not tested to upgrade to 19.10 (it was tested & supported to upgrade to 18.10, and in the future will be tested & supported to upgrade to 20.04 when 20.04.1 has been released), so as described you've performed an untested/unsupported upgrade? or did you re-install? (that should work). You weren't specific with sysrq keys either, examples of something you tried may have helped, and how you upgraded.

Comment: @guiverc Initially, I have installed ubuntu using "ubuntu-18.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso" file then update it to Ubuntu 19.10. So, if I use untested/unsupported upgrade then what should I do? I don't want to loose data also windows I have !

Comment: I get the feeling you used `do-release-upgrade` or `update-manager`.   In most cases it works fine, but 18.04 -> 19.10 was not a tested/supported path so it's now known how good it will go (supported is to next release only, OR from one LTS to next LTS after .1 has been released).  Was it reliable on 18.04?  If it was, I'd likely download the 19.10 ISO & use that (as 'live') for awhile to see how that performs on your hardware, and if it goes well I'd likely re-install using 'something-else' & no-format of partitions. That will note packages, erase system dirs, install, add-back packages..etc

Comment: thanks for your comment
I got crash report in /var/crash is 
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.crash   _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.uploaded
_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1000.upload
Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: +1 experiencing the same issue - this happens quite often when using video conferencing apps. I used to blaze through my tasks with 8 gigs with 16 / 18 release for the record. Feels really bad this is happening with my dev machine :(